Python で特定の文字列の0回以上の繰り返しが末尾に現れるケースを正規表現でマッチさせ、該当文字列を置換したい
特定の文字列の0回以上の繰り返しが末尾に現れたときに、正規表現でマッチさせ、該当文字列を置換したいのですが、期待した通りに動作しません。
私が試したサンプルコード（Python）と、その実行結果・期待値を以下に記載します。
import re

hoge0 = "abc"
hoge1 = "abcHoge"
hoge2 = "abcHogeHoge"
hoge3 = "abcHogeHogeHoge"

print( re.sub("(Hoge)*$", "Fuga", hoge0)) # OK（実行結果：abcFuga     期待値：abcFuga）
print( re.sub("(Hoge)*$", "Fuga", hoge1)) # NG（実行結果：abcFugaFuga 期待値：abcFuga）
print( re.sub("(Hoge)*$", "Fuga", hoge2)) # NG（実行結果：abcFugaFuga 期待値：abcFuga）
print( re.sub("(Hoge)*$", "Fuga", hoge3)) # NG（実行結果：abcFugaFuga 期待値：abcFuga）

このサンプルコードの目的は以下のとおりです。

末尾のHogeをFugaに置き換える
末尾にHogeが何個あっても、またはひとつも無くても、Hogeを消した上でFuga１個に統一する

正規表現の部分は以下のように考えて記載しました。

Hogeをグループと見なすために()で括っています
0回以上の繰り返しに該当させるため、*を使用しています
末尾に来る場合に限定するため、$を使用しています

上記サンプルコードの下３つのケースについて、実行結果にFugaが２回現れましたがこの理由が分かりません。
Fugaが２回現れた理由と、期待値を得るための正規表現の記載方法をご教示ください。

hoge1以降は、"Hoge"の繰り返しで1回、末尾の長さ0の文字列で1回の、合計2回置換されています。
count=1で置換回数を1回に限れば、期待した通りの結果になります。
import re

hoge0 = "abc"
hoge1 = "abcHoge"
hoge2 = "abcHogeHoge"
hoge3 = "abcHogeHogeHoge"

print( re.sub("(Hoge)*$", "Fuga", hoge0, count=1))
print( re.sub("(Hoge)*$", "Fuga", hoge1, count=1))
print( re.sub("(Hoge)*$", "Fuga", hoge2, count=1))
print( re.sub("(Hoge)*$", "Fuga", hoge3, count=1))


なにやら２回置換が行われていることは分かりましたが、この動作原理が理解できませんでした。
末尾に"Hoge"の繰り返しが来た場合にマッチし、マッチしたらそこで正規表現の検索？テスト？が終了するものと考えていました。
今回サンプルコードに挙げた正規表現は、どのような動作をするのか、詳しくご教示ください。
また、これは正規表現の仕様によるものでしょうか。正規表現の仕様や動作原理について深く理解できるwebページや参考書等をご存知でしたら、併せてご教示ください。

単純に「正規表現にマッチする部分を複数回検索する場合は、前回のマッチの終了位置から検索を開始する」というルールに従っているだけです。このルールは、正規表現の末尾が「$」で終わっていても適用されます。例えば"abcHogeHogeHoge"から"(Hoge)$"を検索する場合、まず最初に"HogeHogeHoge"の部分がマッチします。次に、前回のマッチの終了位置、つまり文字列の末尾から再度"(Hoge)$"を検索して、空文字""がマッチする、という動作になっています。

正規表現への理解が浅いため気づいておりませんでしたが、そのようなルールがあったのですね。
確かにそのルールが無いと、例えば"HogeHoge"に対し"Hoge"を検索した際に2個めの"Hoge"にマッチしないので、そのようなルールがあることに得心がいきました。
ご回答ありがとうございました。

理由は、* 0回以上を使用しているため、文末 $ の前に「Fuga」が置換されます。
文末前にHogeがなければ、ひとつFugaが置換され、文末前にHoge複数繰り返しがあれば、その部分がFugaに置換されて、その後文末 $ 前にFugaが置換されるのでFugaFugaとなります。
ご質問の元の文を * を1回以上を表す + あるいは {1,} に変えると、ご期待の結果になります。
修正の文字数を考えると、 + をおすすめいたします。
import re

hoge0 = "abc"
hoge1 = "abcHoge"
hoge2 = "abcHogeHoge"
hoge3 = "abcHogeHogeHoge"

print( re.sub("(Hoge)+$", "Fuga", hoge0))
print( re.sub("(Hoge)+$", "Fuga", hoge1))
print( re.sub("(Hoge)+$", "Fuga", hoge2))
print( re.sub("(Hoge)+$", "Fuga", hoge3))

# あるいは

print( re.sub("(Hoge){1,}$", "Fuga", hoge0))
print( re.sub("(Hoge){1,}$", "Fuga", hoge1))
print( re.sub("(Hoge){1,}$", "Fuga", hoge2))
print( re.sub("(Hoge){1,}$", "Fuga", hoge3))

# hoge0がNGになるので、abcを加えて後方参照を使うと解決します。

print( re.sub("(abc)(Hoge)*$", "\\1Fuga", hoge0))
print( re.sub("(abc)(Hoge)*$", "\\1Fuga", hoge1))
print( re.sub("(abc)(Hoge)*$", "\\1Fuga", hoge2))
print( re.sub("(abc)(Hoge)*$", "\\1Fuga", hoge3))


これだとabcがabcFugaになりませんよね

そうでした。hoge0は期待の結果になりませんね。
その場合は、「*」でcount=1、あるいは、一旦削除してFugaをつけるほうが、簡単ですね。

このルールだとFugaの追加を正規表現でがんばる理由/メリットをまったく感じなくて、
re.sub("(Hoge)*$", "", target) + "Fuga"

の方が、正規表現を複雑にするよりよいのでは? と思いました

look-behind を利用すると以下の様になります。
import re

hoge0 = "abc"
hoge1 = "abcHoge"
hoge2 = "abcHogeHoge"
hoge3 = "abcHogeHogeHoge"

print( re.sub("((Hoge)+|(?<!Hoge))$", "Fuga", hoge0))
print( re.sub("((Hoge)+|(?<!Hoge))$", "Fuga", hoge1))
print( re.sub("((Hoge)+|(?<!Hoge))$", "Fuga", hoge2))
print( re.sub("((Hoge)+|(?<!Hoge))$", "Fuga", hoge3))

# abcFuga
# abcFuga
# abcFuga
# abcFuga

